# How do i pass parameters that is input textbox value to ajax in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters

My Ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sub").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "jqueryphp.php",
            data: "txt1=" + txt1,
            success: function(result) {
                $("div").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

This is the form code . I want to pass txt1 value to Ajax

```
<input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" /><br>
<input type="button" name="sub" id="sub" value="click Me" />
```

I want to pass **txt1** value to my php page using this Ajax function.

Please tell me what exactly will come in the data attribute of Ajax

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Send data as an object instead of a string and to retreive the value of the text field, use val():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sub").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "jqueryphp.php",
            data: {
                txt1: $("#txt1").val()
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $("div").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: @user1205245 try setting a `dataType`

Comment: You could also try to set `cache: "false"` as some have reported [IE caching issues](http://www.gtothesquare.com/2010/09/26/if-jquery-ajax-call-not-working-in-internet-explorer-try-this/)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sub").click(function() {
    var txt1 = $("#txt1").val(); //textbox value
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "jqueryphp.php",
            cache: false,
            data: "txt1=" + txt1,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(result) {
                $("div").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: @DemoUser. I used your code for my ajax code. It's working. I have small doubt here  data: "txt1=" + txt1, Here i used  data: txt1, is not woking. But all other code this way. But i used this is not working why. Is there any problem my browser