# Jquery IE. ajax request running only once

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the code . Ajax is only running once when i run in the IE. But with all other browsers it is running great.
    
    
    
    
    Untitled Document
    
    
    function cool_add()
    {   //alert(post_id);
     var txt1 = $("#txt1").val();
    $.post('jqueryphp.php', {txt1:txt1}, function(data) {
    var dat = data;
     $("div").html(data);
        });
    }

```
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
<input type="text" id="txt1" /><br />
<input type="button" id="butn" onclick="cool_add();">
</form>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is running great in all other browsers but with IE it only runs once thats it.

Answer (score 2):

IE tends to cache all request and if the request params are same then it will return the cached response. To avoid this, you can use [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) following code which will be applied globally for any future ajax calls.

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
      // Disable caching of AJAX responses
      cache: false,
});
```

You can also apply this `cache` on a specific call as below,

```
$.ajax ( {
     //..other params
     cache: false,
     //..other params
});
```

When `cache=false`, jQuery will add current timestamp to each request so that the request params are unique.

Comment: @user1205245 You can add ajaxSetup to your common script.. any common params that you want to implement can be added to the ajaxSetup. Read ajaxSetup documentation for details. If you want it on a specific call, you can use cache param on that specific call..

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call, make sure to include

```
cache: false
```

IE caches everything, so it assumes your calls are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is the caching issue I identified in your [question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372033/how-do-i-pass-parameters-that-is-input-textbox-value-to-ajax-in-jquery/9372087#comment11836574_9372087).

http://www.gtothesquare.com/2010/09/26/if-jquery-ajax-call-not-working-in-internet-explorer-try-this/